# Trouble obtaining previous value in a for loop without messing it all up

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains total flu cases in a week, the date recorded and four population columns pop2010, pop2011, pop2012, pop2013. I have calculated weekly infection rate by doing infectionRate/PertinentPopulation*100000. So far everything fine.

However, now I want to create a moving average by doing (currentWeek + previousWeek).mean() / PertinentPopulation * 100000. I have tried doing this:

```
for index, row in enumerate(df.itertuples(index=False)):
    print((df.iloc[index, df.columns.get_loc('flu_pos')] + df.iloc[index-1, df.columns.get_loc('flu_pos')]).mean()
```

But the problem of using index-1 is that when index is zero, the result is -1, which means it looks into the last row and messes all up.

How can I get the code to ignore doing the moving average ONLY the first row?

To clarify, this is what I have:

```
flu_pos  date        pop2010  pop2012  pop2012  pop2013  week_rate  2weekAvg_rate
5        01-01-2010  100      200      300      400      5000       nan
10       10-01-2010  100      200      300      400      10000      nan
15       20-01-2010  100      200      300      400      15000      nan
20       30-01-2010  100      200      300      400      20000      nan
```

This is what I would like to get (in first week the average is ignored but kicks off after first week):

```
flu_pos  date        pop2010  pop2012  pop2012  pop2013  week_rate  2weekAvg_rate
5        01-01-2010  100      200      300      400      5000       5000
10       10-01-2010  100      200      300      400      10000      7500
15       20-01-2010  100      200      300      400      15000      12500
20       30-01-2010  100      200      300      400      20000      17500
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if-else statement for this. Here is pseudocode, for what you can do:

```
for index, row in enumerate(df.itertuples(index=False)):
    if index > 0:
        #code for moving average
    else:
        #use df.iloc to set the value for the cell in the first row
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take `rolling` `mean`, though this assumes you have a single row for every week.

```
df['2weekAvg_rate'] = df['week_rate'].rolling(2, min_periods=1).mean()
```

---

```
   flu_pos        date  pop2010  pop2012  pop2012.1  pop2013  week_rate  2weekAvg_rate
0        5  01-01-2010      100      200        300      400       5000         5000.0
1       10  10-01-2010      100      200        300      400      10000         7500.0
2       15  20-01-2010      100      200        300      400      15000        12500.0
3       20  30-01-2010      100      200        300      400      20000        17500.0
```

Comment: Hi ALollz, this looks good and I tried it but when I implement the you code you suggest it this: AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'rolling'